# Android Studio : The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm trying to install my app debug from my android studio. it's work well yesterday, but today when i try to install it again, the application cant be installed on my device and showing error like below on my android studio.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE
The device timed out while trying to install the application.
Retry
```

what should i do? i tried install on other device, and it worked fine. My device is Redmi 4X and other device is Samsung J3

Comment: `File -> Invalidate Caches Restart` did not work for me. I had to delete the `*.lock` files in my AVD at `/home/ubuntu/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_30.avd/*.lock` and restart the emulator

Comment: My comment might help someone. In my case there was no space left on the device. Removing some data made it work again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Faced the same issue, not sure of the reason but in Android studio, Click on the File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart and then it starts to work.

Answer (score 8):

I got same issue with my device. i restart my device and its work properly.

Comment: Worked for me once.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you don't have the proper SDK for the Android version. I'm telling you because a month has passed for me too. The solution is to download the appropriate pack in the SDK Manager.

If you have doubts how to enter:

1. Close the project.
2. In the welcome panel click on settings, then choose the SDK Manager option.
3. Click show package details and select the version for Android and choose all packages.
4. Finally you click ok XD

Try this method if it works perfect greetings

Answer (score 1):

Android studio -> setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment ->  Debugger -> Android Debug Bright (adb) -> Check use libusb backend

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If other answers didn't help and previously application was installing correctly on your device, try to check your AndroidManifest file. Check that nothing forbids to install your app because of os version conflict or manifest merging errors or other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently, through process of elimination I determined the cause was related to dependencies in the build.gradle(your app name).

I suggest working backwards and comment out everything that was added since the last known working build/install.

In my case I have a legacy app developed back in 2016 being rewritten, dependencies for signalR have changed quite a bit since then, the original libs where causing the install to fail while everything else seemed excellent, not even a single build error was occurring. Commenting out the libs and references got the application to a runnable state.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **I deleted the emulator and recreated it**. It solved the issue.
Before this, I had already tried following which did not work for me:

- From menu: File->Invalidate cache/restart.
- Deleting .cxx, .idea, .gradle, build folders and rebuilding.
- Cold boot device emulator

Posting this in case someone is trapped in my kind of situation.